# CSS Smooth drop down menu

Tags: css, wordpress, webkit

I have a vertical nav menu on which I want to be able to hover on parent items in order to reveal their children. I'd like the children to "fall" from their parent and "push" the other items in doing so (children aren't displayed at first).

Here's my failed attempt on CSS using webkit transitions and translate:

```
.children a {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 50px); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50px); /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, 50px);

  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.page_item_has_children:hover .children a {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-22 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/About/">About</a>
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item page-item-81"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/About/Me">Me</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-83"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/About/Us">Us</a></li>
</ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/Page1/">Page1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/Page2/">Page2</a></li>

</li>
    </nav>
```

(This is PHP-generated for Wordpress).

So what I'd want is for Me and Us to "fall" from About when hover.

I know I used `translate` wrong because this pushes the children items when I want them to fall where they belong from higher above. I hope I'm being clear. Thanks so much!

Comment: can you post your html, too?

Comment: Just edited. Thank you for your help, highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to set a background color on your main menu, absolutely position the sub menu, use a negative `z-index` to put the submenu under the parent, then use `transform: translateY()` to do the transition.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

.site-nav {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.children {
  transition: all .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.page_item_has_children:hover .children {
  transform: translate(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.children {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav">
  <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="page_item page-item-22 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/About/">About</a>
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="page_item page-item-81"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/About/Me">Me</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-83"><a href="http://localhost:8888/myWebsite/About/Us">Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!! However I have othere items under "About" and would like those to be pushed down. Updated the html right now.